# MSBuild - Override configuration property by using configuration property

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

I found on the internet that one can use `msbuild.exe -property=<PropertyName>=<value>` to override a property during build. For example I could use `msbuild.exe -property=OutDir=bin\ABC` to change the output directory.

Now my question is, is it possible to use other configuration properties in the override statement. Meaning I want to achieve something like this: `msbuild.exe -property=OutDir=$(SolutionDir)Output\$(AssemblyName)\$(AssemblyVersion)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot do that. The msbuild command line assigning properties method cannot parse how MSBuild gets the value --`$(XXX)`. That is designed by that.

If you do that, you will get the output folder called `$(SolutionDir)Output\$(AssemblyName)\$(AssemblyVersion)` under the current cd folder.

So you should only use the direct full path for `outdir` under msbuild command line.

If you still get what you want, you should abandon msbuild command line assigning properties method and instead, add this under `xxx.csproj` file directly.

```
<PropertyGroup>

<OutDir>$(SolutionDir)Output\$(AssemblyName)\$(AssemblyVersion)</Outdir>

</PropertyGroup>
```

Use `msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:build` directly to build the project.